# Why did fetch stop working in Excel Addin after updating manifest to point to files host in Azure?

Tags: office-js

I created a task pane Excel add-in using visual studio. The add-in calls custom APIs using FETCH. Everything worked perfectly during development. The FETCH responses were successful and the data parsed into my spreadsheet. However, once I published the files to azure, updated the manifest file, and deployed it with centralized deployment the FETCH does not call AT ALL. The manifest file uploads with no issues, I added the API URLs to the App Domain section of the manifest file like below:

```
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://td-officeapps-api-dev.azurewebsites.net</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>

                            fetch('https://td-officeapps-api-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/service-estimate/opportunityByNumber/' + rng.text, {
                                method: "GET",
                                headers: {
                                    'x-key': 'XXXXXXXX',
                                },
                            })

                                .then(function (response) {
                                    return response.json();

                                    if (response.status !== 404 || reponse.status !== 200) {
                                        $('#notice').text("Oops, something went wrong while getting this data. Please use the 'Get Support' button to contact your IT team.");
                                        return
                                    }

                                })
                                .then(function (data) {
                                    if (data.message == "Opportunity - " + rng.text + " not found") {
                                        $('#notice').text("Opportunity - " + rng.text + " not found. Please enter another opportunity ID and try again.");
                                        return
                                    }
                                    //input data on Setup sheet
                                    var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet("SETUP"); //Change to setup in production.
                                    sheet.protection.unprotect();
                                    //project center
                                    sheet.getRange("ProfitCenter").values = data.data.profitCenter;
```

Like i said this is not a syntax errror with code because everything works perfect when the manifest referencing the files on my local machine. Its only after the manifest it changed to reference the files in Azure that the FETCH quits working. Look forward to any insight!

Comment: Do the custom api's need to be published to the same app service in  Azure? seems strange if so because why have the app domain settings in the manifest XML?

Comment: Also the function with the fetch is being called from a button click on the task pane. When I click it nothing happens.

Comment: You don't need that `<AppDomain>` if **td-officeapps-api-dev.azurewebsites.net** is the same domain as in `<SourceLocation>` in the manifest. See [AppDomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/appdomain). It sounds like the button handler is not running. How are you determining that?

Comment: I think I firgured it out - due to CORS error between API's app service and the excel addin app service. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It was a CORS issue. Someone else made the modification in Azure for me.